# I want to know why the program worked in eclipse but was not able to submit in Codejam

Tags: java

I tried to attend in google code jam and in qualification round when I submit it I got WA(Wrong Answer). When it worked fine in my eclipse can I know the problem with my code so I can fix my code. I also got the correct output when I tried to test my program with sample input and output.

Input

```
4

3

360 480

420 540

600 660

3

0 1440

1 3

2 4

5

99 150

1 100

100 301

2 5

150 250

2

0 720

720 1440
```

Output

```
Case #1: CJC

Case #2: IMPOSSIBLE

Case #3: JCCJJ

Case #4: CC
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int T=0;
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        T = a.nextInt();
        int cases=0;
        String work[][] = new String[T][1000];
        String data[] = new String[T];
        while(T>cases) {
            //System.out.println("cases: "+cases);//debug
            int N=a.nextInt();
            int J[][] = new int[N][2];
            int C[][] = new int[N][2];
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
                //System.out.println("For : i"+ i);//debug
                int Si = a.nextInt();
                int Ei = a.nextInt();
                boolean check = true;
                boolean check1 =true;
                for(int k=0;k<i;k++) {
                    if(Si>=J[k][0]&&Si<J[k][1]) {
                        check=false;
                    }
                    if(Ei>J[k][0]&&Ei<=J[k][1]) {
                        check=false;
                    }
                    if(Si>=C[k][0]&&Si<C[k][1]) {
                        check1=false;
                    }
                    if(Ei>C[k][0]&&Ei<=C[k][1]) {
                        check1=false;
                    }
                }
                if(check) {
                    //System.out.println("Upgrade1");
                    J[i][0] = Si;
                    J[i][1] = Ei;
                    work[cases][i] = "J";
                }else if(check1) {
                    //System.out.println("Upgrade2");
                    C[i][0] = Si;
                    C[i][1] = Ei; 
                    work[cases][i] = "C";
                }else
                    work[cases][i]= "I";
            }
            for(int k=0;k<N;k++) {
                //System.out.println("N: "+ N);
                if(k==0)
                    data[cases] = work[cases][k];
                else
                    data[cases]+=work[cases][k];
            }
            cases++;
        }
        for(int k=0;k<T;k++) {
            if(data[k].contains("I")) {
                data[k]="Impossible";
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++) {
            //System.out.println("Printing");

            System.out.println("Case #" + (i+1) + ": "+ data[i]);           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is wrong in "Codejam"?

Comment: And adding an extra `\n` everywhere has nothing to do with the `WA`?